# How to automatically move computer object from computers

Tags: powershell

I need a powershell script to move computer objects from Computers in Active directory according to the following conditions

- It will check the username written in the description in the computer object (Username is written on each computer)
- Moves the computer to the OU where the user is located.

I used the -SearchBase command while preparing the script but without success;

$ComputerObject = Read-Host "CN=$ComputerObject,OU=Computers,DC=domain,DC=com"

Get-ADComputer -Filter -SearchBase "OU=Computers,DC=domain,DC=com"

Move-ADObject –Identity (I don't know what to write here.)

Is there anyone who can help?

Comment: Define need. You want us to write the script for you?

Comment: Please show the code attempt.

Comment: $ComputerObject = Read-Host "CN=$ComputerObject,OU=Computers,DC=domain,DC=com"

Get-ADComputer -Filter -SearchBase "OU=Computers,DC=domain,DC=com"

Move-ADObject –Identity (I don't know what to write here.)

Comment: This doesn't look like you tried at all. Powershell is all about self-discoverability, run `Get-Help cmdlet-name` to see the syntax and basic functionality of the cmdlet. So, a quick look at `Read-Host` says it prompts the user for input. So you're prompting the user with an *OU* (*why*?), then assigning the input to a variable that's not used.

Comment: Bad idea. By moving computer objects to the users OU, Group Policies will also work on these where you really want that separated.